# Cordova resume event not firing in one device

Tags: android, cordova, event-handling

We develop a hybrid app with cordova through visual studio. We have a problem with the resume event in one of the device tested.

Within the app you can see a pdf file which is viewed with the default viewer. When pressing the back button and our app shows again, the resume event should be fired. In 2 devices with android 4.1 & 4.3 resume event is fired as expected. In my phone (elephone P3000) with android 4.4 (the phone is rooted) resume event is never fired.

It happens in all version of cordova > 3.4.

What should we check for?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Device>Settings>Developer Options >Apps: Dont Keep activities** is checked by default in some android devices, if you uncheck this option, the apps will not be killed on back button press, it will stay paused in background and resumed on retrieves from background.

Comment: excallent... this fixed my problem. Thanks a lot